# Поиск в django: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, solr

> Здравствуйте, недавно начал изучать django, вот дошел до поиска и вот такая ошибка: 
>       AttributeError at /blog/search/
>       'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
>   при вводе в поле поиска значения, которого нет в индексе, возвращает пустое значение, если ввести значение, которое есть - вернет вот это:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/search/?q=proverka

Django Version: 1.9.2
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'haystack',
 'blog',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/query.py" in post_process_results
  213.                     index = ui.get_index(model)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py" in get_index
  308.             raise NotHandled('The model %s is not registered' % model_klass)

During handling of the above exception (The model None is not registered), another exception occurred:

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/generic_views.py" in get
  123.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/generic_views.py" in form_valid
  80.             'object_list': self.queryset

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get_context_data
  134.             paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in paginate_queryset
  78.             page = paginator.page(page_number)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  55.         return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/query.py" in __getitem__
  272.                 self._fill_cache(start, bound)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/query.py" in _fill_cache
  191.         to_cache = self.post_process_results(results)

File "/home/yurka/VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/query.py" in post_process_results
  219.                     loaded_objects[model] = model._default_manager.in_bulk(models_pks[model])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/search/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

вот view для поиска:

```
class PostSearch(SearchView):
    template_name = 'blog/post/search.html'
    queryset = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).load_all()
    total_results = queryset.count()
    form_class = SearchForm
```

вот шаблон:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if "q" in request.GET %}
        <h1>Posts containing "{{ q }}"</h1>
        <h3>Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize }}</h3>
        {% for result in queryset %}
            {% with post=result.object %}
                <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
            {% endwith %}
        {% empty %}
            <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <p><a href="{% url "blog:haystack_search" %}">Search again</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Search for posts</h1>
        <form action="." method="get">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

в моделях ничего необычного нет. Вот еще установленные модули:

> Django==1.9.2 
>   django-haystack==2.4.1 
>   django-taggit==0.18.0
>   elasticsearch==2.3.0 
>   Markdown==2.6.5 
>   pysolr==3.4.0 
>   pytz==2015.7
>   requests==2.9.1 
>   urllib3==1.14 
>   wheel==0.29.0

в самом поиске ищется, что в elastic, что в solr.

Comment: P.S. Подозреваю, что или версия django сильно новая, либо haystack старый

Answer (score 1):

вот нашел в документации haystack:Haystack currently only supports ElasticSearch 1.x. **ElasticSearch 2.x is not supported yet**